# Non US-centric databases on boards of directors and government agency memberships?

Tags: government, companies

Are there any open (and preferably inter/multinational, not just US) databases on membership to boards of directors and leaders of government agencies?

For instance, Little Sis has mostly US data (http://littlesis.org/features). What about the rest of the world? Is the only current alternative to fish similar data on a country-by-country basis?

Answer (score 4):

From corporate boards of directors, OpenCorporates is a fantastic resource for this kind of thing, if a bit intimidating to wade through.  They do have lots of US data, but also UK, and many other jurisdictions.  It's all scraper-assembled, so not quite as clean as you get from LittleSis, but you can definitely find corporate officers.

I'm a little fuzzy on what you're asking for with respect to governments.  Do you want a list of government employees?  Or a list of corporate actors who serve in government capacities (on advisory committees and the like?)

Comment: OpenCorporates seems great, thanks. About government agencies: I am looking only for leads of government agencies, not full lists of government employees. I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: Okay.  There have been a few attempts at doing things like this in a US context (e.g., <a href="http://php.app.com/fed_employees11/search.php">this</a>, which is all US federal employees), but I don't know of any unified international datasets like this, especially if you want career civil servants instead of elected officials, which it sounds like you do.

Comment: I invited Chris Taggart from open corporates into the Beta so he can provide more info on what they offer through their API.

Comment: Thanks for all the kind comments about OpenCorporates. Just a quick clarification – an increasing number of countries are now supplying us the information as data. Also while scraping is not an exact science, I would say the quality of our scraping, particularly for info such as the directors is pretty good, in part because we have quite a few checks on the data, and in part because people are fairly quick to let us know of problems (one of the advantages to being open on the web). Incidentally, we do get emails that info is wrong, but it's usually wrong at the official register!

Answer (score 1):

Check out Poderopedia, which aims to provide this service for Chile.
http://poderopedia.org/